# animate uilabel to textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uilabel, uitextview

I'm doing an app where i'm making a user log in and profile for each user. I'm now creating a function where the users are able to change their profile text. I'm therefor thinking if it is possible to change the UILabel to a UITextview and can this be done using some kind of animation? I prefer this since it creates a better user experience instead of switching back and forward between viewcontrollers just to change a small text.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just do away with a label and use a text field/text view and toggle the `allowsEditing` property as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need use `UILabel` for it?
More better will be if you init your `UITextFeild` this way:

```
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Don't forget add `UITextFieldDelegate` in class interface. Then you able catch moments, when text field starts editing via it's delegate method -- `textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField`. Here you can change background of text field how you need or add some animation for text etc.
To catch moment when user left text field (i.e. press "Return" button on keyboard), use method `textFieldDidEndEditing:textField`. There you can back text fields style to default.